# Convert decimal to a string in php

Tags: php

I have this line of decimal code:

> 65 97 66 98 67 99 68 100 69 101

If converted to text it'd display

> AaBbCcDdEe

Would there be any way to do so in PHP?

Comment: you can use strval() function to convert a number to a string in php. check out this page to test it https://progzoo.net/wiki/PHP:Convert_a_Number_to_a_String

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explode numbers and use chr function. You can see result [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c2ddc4c4148d88b784478aa0896e2b5017edb88a)

```
$numbers = '65 97 66 98 67 99 68 100 69 101';

foreach (explode(' ', $numbers) as $number) {
    echo chr($number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a `chr` function which does this. (Read documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chr.php))

If your "line of decimal code" is `65 97 66 98 67 99 68 100 69 101`, you can do the following

```
$string = '65 97 66 98 67 99 68 100 69 101';
$arr = explode(' ', $string);
$output = '';
foreach ($arr as $char) {
    $output .= chr($char);
}
echo $output;
```

The output will be `AaBbCcDdEe`.